# When is $C^\infty(M)$ a division ring?

Tags: modules, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions, tangent-bundle

Given a smooth manifold $M$ and its tangent bundle $TM$, the set of vector fields on $M$, denoted $\Gamma(TM)$, is a module over the commutative algebra of smooth functions on $M$, denoted $C^\infty(M)$. Now, since every nonzero module over a division ring has a basis by Zorn's lemma, I was wondering if there are any smooth manifolds $M$ with $C^\infty(M)$ as a division ring. If so, what are the conditions on $M$?

Comment: A smooth function is invertible if and only if it's nowhere zero. So your question is equivalent to asking: For which smooth manifolds is it true that every nonzero smooth function is *nowhere* zero? But since you can always subtract a constant from a smooth function to get another smooth function, this is the same as asking, for which manifolds are all smooth functions constant?

Comment: $M=\{\mathrm{pt}\}$ is the only such manifold : $M$ has to be connected otherwise there are nontrivial idempotents. If $M$ has positive dimension the presence of bump functions (for instance) yields nontrivial zero divisors in $C^\infty(M)$.

Comment: The zero module has a basis too! It's empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $m \in M$ is any point, $C^{\infty}(M)$ has a maximal ideal given by the kernel of the evaluation map $C^{\infty}(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ at $m$. $C^{\infty}(M)$ is a field iff it has no nontrivial ideals so this ideal must be zero, and (with a little effort) this implies $m = M$; that is, $M$ must consist of a single point.

As for your motivation, vector fields form not only a module but a finitely generated [projective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module) module over $C^{\infty}(M)$ (by the smooth [Serre-Swan theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%E2%80%93Swan_theorem)), so a less restrictive version of your question is to ask when every such module is free. This is true, for example, if $M = \mathbb{R}^n$, but otherwise almost never true, e.g. it is never true if the (even) [$K$-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-theory) $K^0(M)$ of $M$ is nontrivial, and $K$-theory is nontrivial whenever even rational cohomology $H^{2\bullet}(M, \mathbb{Q})$ is nontrivial due to the existence of the [Chern character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern_class) isomorphism, at least if $M$ is compact.

Finally, the least restrictive version of your question is to ask when vector fields themselves form a free module. Manifolds with this property are called [parallelizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold); examples include the spheres $S^1, S^3, S^7$ as well as any [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) and any orientable $3$-manifold, but generally speaking examples are rare. A parallelizable manifold has the property that all of its [characteristic classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_class) vanish which is quite a strong condition.